# In Python, without inporting anything, is it possible to do constant time searching on a Double Ended Priority Queue?

Tags: python-2.7, heap

Double Ended Priority Queue is implemented using Interval Heaps. 
My double ended priority queue is of the form [['abc',xyz'],['c'.'t'],['f','n']]; so here minimum is 'abc' and maximum is 'xyz'. Heap is represented as list.

Comment: it's possible to do anything that can be done in python without importing anything

Comment: what I mean is if you are suggesting a way, suggest it without any libraries.